# cognosdotnet_10_2 and spreadsheetML output

Tags: sdk, base64, cognos, spreadsheetml

Trying to get **spreadsheetML** output from Cognos using cognosdotnet_10_2.dll.

"Outputpage" data is base64 encoded string. I'm trying to get something readable out of base64string to plainText variable. I have tried with basically most of the basic encodings and **result doesn't look like markup.**

```
var encodedTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(((asynchDetailReportOutput)res.details[i]).outputPages[0]);

plainText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encodedTextBytes);
```

Does anyone have ideas what to try next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

encodedTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(((asynchDetailReportOutput)res.details[i]).outputPages[0]);

FileStream fs = new FileStream(outputPath, FileMode.Create);
fs.Write(encodedTextBytes, 0, encodedTextBytes.Length);